How to receive multiple parameter using AJAX
I am trying to send multiple parameter using AJAX. My JavaScript code is like below.
$('.overview_value').change(function() {    
    $('#overview').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pageLength: 100,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: baseUrl+'/owner/safety/overview_result/'+$("#time").val()+'/'+$("#property_id").val()+'/'+$("#unit_id").val()+'/'+$("#status").val(),
        order: [1, 'desc'],
        ordering: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        drawCallback: function () {
            $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm");
        },
        language: {
            'paginate': {
                'previous': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-left"></span>',
                'next': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-right"></span>'
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "data": "property_id",
            },
            {
                "data": "unit_id",
            },
            {
                "data": "issue_date",
            },
            {
                "data": "expiry_date",
            },
            {
                "data": "certified_by",
            },
            {
                "data": "safety",
            },
            {
                "data": "reminder",
            },
        ]
    });
});

My route is like below.
 Route::get('overview_result/{time}/{property}/{unit}/{status}', [OverviewController::class, 'overview_result'])->name('overview_result');

My Controller code is like below.
public function overview_result( $time, $property, $unit, $status )
    {
        if ($time == 'all') {
            $difference = Carbon::now()->addYears(100);
        }
        if ($time == 'oneweek') {
            $difference = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->addWeek();
        }
        if ($time == 'onemonth') {
            $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth();
        }
        if ($time == 'threemonth') {
            $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonths(3)->endOfMonth();
        }
        if ($time == 'sixmonth') {
            $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonths(6)->endOfMonth();
        }

        $data = Safety::with(['property', 'propertyUnit'])
            ->where('property_id', $property)
            ->where('unit_id', $unit)
            ->whereBetween('expiry_date', [Carbon::now(), $difference])
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->get();

        return $data;
    }

How can I receive multiple parameters inside overview_result function ?

Use it like this no need to add params with URL. just add in data array like below code.
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table1').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": baseUrl+'/owner/safety/overview_result/',
                "data": function(d) {
                    // Add your custom parameters here
                    d.time = $("#time").val();
                    d.property_id = $("#property_id").val();
                    d.unit_id = $("#unit_id").val();
                    d.status = $("#status").val();
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "property_id",
                },
                {
                    "data": "unit_id",
                },
                {
                    "data": "issue_date",
                },
                {
                    "data": "expiry_date",
                },
                {
                    "data": "certified_by",
                },
                {
                    "data": "safety",
                },
                {
                    "data": "reminder",
                },
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

and In the controller, you can receive these parameters like this.
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PropertyController extends Controller
{
   public function overview_result(Request $request){
     $request->query('time');
     $request->query('property_id');
     $request->query('unit_id');
     $request->query('status');
   }

